# Is Artemis Fowl II’s fairy communicator feasible?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, near-future

In the book Artemis Fowl: The Lost Colony, Artemis is contacted by Holly through a fairy communicator, disguised as a ring.

> The phone was disguised as a rather ostentatious ring on Artemis's middle finger. Artemis twisted the ring so that the phone sat on his palm, then closed his middle fingers, extending his thumb and little finger. The sensor would decode vibrations in his little finger and send them as voice patterns. It would also use the bones in his hand to transmit the caller's voice to the tip of his thumb.
>   Artemis looked for all the world like a young boy talking on an imaginary phone.

My question is, what would be the (estimated) costs of R&D, and of the actual product?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! Great to see a fellow Artemis Fowl fan here. I think this may fall into the category of "questions about an existing world", and may get closed as a result, but I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: My daughter has a bluetooth glove with an earpiece in the thumb and mic in the pinky.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for estimated costs of R&D for an "actual product" ( which is actually entirely fictional) is not Worldbuilding.

Comment: I have a feeling that only answers you'd get for the cost of R&D would be guesses at best, and the final product price is entirely subjective based on the market. Bone conduction is a real thing, and I kind of doubt that pinky vibrations would be usable, a small mic in the ring solves this. Generally speaking, I'd say that you can use whatever numbers that you want for both, or just not give numbers and be better off.

Comment: Wouldn't work. The fluid in the joints would damp most of your signal before it got to the palm.Think of it as a string telephone with the string dipped in a bowl of water halfway along its length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no fixed costs for R&D. It will depend on how much info and the level of detail you want. If you want to keep it strictly technical, with today electronics you could buy a protoboard and some parts online and then play with them in your garage. Once you have a prototype ready you can 3D print them or send the blueprints to a factory. Depending on where you live in the world you may end up investing from a few thousand dollars in North America to a few dozen thousand dollars in South America<sup>1</sup>, for example.

A big corporation, on the other hand, might invest millions in visual design, testing prototypes with end users in multiple markets, pay lawyers to analyze the minimal legal requirements to be able to sell in various different countries, buy patents to be on the safe side of IP etc. Again, a precise sum cannot be provided. We can at best guess here.

As for a final price... I could find some devices that will perform the same function as that ring, but in glove form (as per Pojo-guy's comment). That will give you an idea of the final end user price, since both the fabric used for a glove and the metal for a ring will be a very minor part of the cost. [Check these ones out, going for 44-63 dollars](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009NBRXLQ). If your product becomes successful, expect chinese variations costing a third of yours hitting the shelves in poorer countries.

<sup>1</sup> I kid you not. Stuff is expensive in some places. In Brazil, for example, electronics usually cost 2.5x to 9x what they cost in the United States. Most of the extra costs are import taxes.

Comment: Good answer - could have gone a bit more into the tech needed for the individual parts e.g. https://hackaday.com/2015/02/08/turning-an-ordinary-pen-into-a-covert-radio-receiver/  but as all of the tech is available to the consumer at varying levels of fidelity, the question really becomes "hacker or corporation"